# Simulink implementation of Fourier Transform Property of Integration and Differentiation (Part 2)

Tags: integration, fft, simulink, ifft, differentiation

So this is a continuation of the thread in this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677430/simulink-implementation-of-fourier-transform-property-of-integration-and-differe#

I've made some progress (I think) and I now have this:

[image]

The output in scope1 is obviously incorrect, but I'm not sure what i have to edit to make it correct. The signal in the sign wave is 10pi. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your model, and I think the problem is here:
[image]

You have the real signal at sine. After using FFT you got complex signal with nonzero real part and zero imaginary part. And then you multiply it at imaginary number.

So after that you already have signal with zero real part. I didn't check further, but I think simulink works correct.